# Как запустить python скрипт после определённых действий на сайте

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть сайт и там есть форма входа, при которой запрашиваться почта, надо чтобы после ввода почты выполнялся скрипт на python, после этого сайт запрашивает код который придёт на почту и при вводе этого кода, должен запуститься второй python скрипт. Важно то что при выполнении обоих этих скриптов у них должны быть переменные с этого сайта, то есть при запросе почты, она должны сохраниться куда-то и быть использована в python скрипте, так же с кодом. Как это сделать?

Заранее огромное спасибо!

Comment: сайт на Django ?

Comment: @Интик думаю нет. Иначе зачем выполнять сторонние скрипты на питоне, когда их можно в логику самой Django закинуть